# How to click on a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Web Console in Firefox to run some Java script commands and, in a website, i would like to know how click on a button 10 times using Java script?

I'm trying the following code, but did not work! He clicks one time only.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.getElementById('btnMoreVideos').click();
    //sleep(1000); //If i uncomment, it doesn't work to.
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you are trying to do some spam ?!

Comment: lol i guess too :D eheh

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cV2WZ/1/).

Comment: "it did not work" is not a problem, it's an opinion. Please describe what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, ideally with something like a jsfiddle.net that has your code running in it to prove the code does what you claim it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it clicks 10 times just very fast. If you want to click it 10 times with some interval - you have to use `setInterval` function. There is not `sleep()` function in javascript.

```
  var clicked = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('btnMoreVideos').click();
    clicked++;
    if (clicked >= 10)
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000);
```